# Wordpress Custom Posts Template in Grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

So I'm just starting to learn wordpress, i've finished a few courses about html/css and javascript/jquery by now.I can't figure out how to use a html template i made for custom post type, that i want to be displayed in certain grid.This is the thing in html/css:
[Service's Cards Post Type](https://codepen.io/Hala1892/pen/rKXZOX)

So basically I need to use a template like that:

```
    <div class="card">
    <div class="service">
         <div class="circle"></div>
         <img src="<php field here>" class="service-image">
<div class="card-text">
<h4 class="card-title"><php field here></h4>
<p class="card-info"><php field here></p></div>
        </div></div>
```

So each time i create a post from a custom post type i created about that, i have that template with those three fields and the other divs without input.I'm not sure what exactly I should be looking for, so I will appreciate help, even just the path for the solution.Like what articles and tutorials I should be looking for to achieve that.Thanks

Comment: Do you have the CSS for your classes included in your project?

Comment: Yes, they are included in the main css file.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what i'v done, so if it helps somone, it would be great:

1.Create a custom post type(to target the post type later, but it's not necessary, you could do it by category, id etc.):
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

2.Visualize the post grid via post loop in the page I need:

```
<?php 
$args = array('post_type' => 'cptname'); /* create variable with the post type characteristics you want to display.*/
$loop = new WP_Query($args);/* new variable making the $args into wp_query */
if ($loop->have_posts()):/* if cptname have posts do that */
    while( $loop->have_posts()) :$loop->the_post();?>/* while cptname have posts take the post */
<?php get_template_part('custom','type'); ?>/* the template of the cpt */
<?php endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

More arguments you may want to add: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

3.Create the template of the cpt.

In this scenario I need a new file called custom-type.php and there I have to store how i want my cpt's posts to display.In my example I have a thumbnail,a title with an url and two custom post fields - Prize and Information.

For the thumbnail:

```
<img class="your-image" <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
```

For the title:

```
<?php the_title( sprintf('<h1 class="your-title"><a href="%s">', esc_url(get_permalink())),'</a></h1>'); ?>
```

For the custom post fields:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Information', true ); ?>
<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Prize', true ); ?>
```

4.Create the custom post type's Single Page.
Here I had to create a new file called single-(the name of the cpt).php and then call pretty much same functions as before plus the one for content:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

There are a lot more you can use.This one is for how you want the single page for each post on this custom post type look like.

Hope that help someone, and if there is something i did wrong or missed, I'm all about to listen and learn more.Thanks :)